# string.toUpperCase difficulties

Tags: javascript

I'm making slow progress with my self education and I've run into a problem. I'm attempting to get text input from the user. I then want that input to be check against an uppercase version of itself. I'm running the code through labs.codecademy.com(if that is relevant).

Code:

```
function rollerInput() {
    var input = prompt("Do you want to reroll? You have " + rerolls + " rerolls left. Y/N?");
    input = input.toUpperCase;
    if(input === null) {
        console.log("Please enter Y or N");
        rollerInput();
        } else if(input === "") {
            console.log("Please enter Y or N");
            rollerInput();
        } else if(input === "Y" && rerolls !== 1) {
            rerolls = rerolls -1;
            reRoller();
        } else if(input === "Y" && rerolls === 1) {
            console.log("You have no rerolls left.");   
        }
}
```

The issue lies with the ifs that check for Y or N. Neither Y nor y produce any reaction. I'm sure I'm missing something simple, but I can't fix it to save my life.

Comment: It is a method and you have to call it using brackets `()`: `input = input.toUpperCase();`

Comment: @GregHewgill & SterlingArcher thanks! My mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`input = input.toUpperCase` stores the *function* `toUpperCase` in the variable `input`. You want to *invoke* the function.

Use

```
input = input.toUpperCase();
```

This is the difference between `x = function () { }` and `x = (function() { })()` - the first one stores a function, the second one executes a function and stores the return value.

The other problem is that you're blindly invoking `toUpperCase` *before* you check for `null`. That'll lead to an error if the user cancels the dialog. You need to move your test inside your `null` check when you know that `input.toUpperCase` will actually be defined.

Comment: I feel exceptionally embarrassed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`toUpperCase` is a method and you have to call it using brackets `()`

```
input = input.toUpperCase();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you didn't call the function.

```
input = input.toUpperCase();
```